# Stop macOS from creating synthesized disks from an APFS partition?

Tags: disk-utility, apfs

I have a raw dump of an APFS partition that I've created so that I can roll back a system to an exact state for testing. This dump was created using `dd`, and is not created form any of the volumes inside the container, but rather the entire APFS partition from the physical disk.

I'd like to restore it back on to the physical disk using `dd`, and normally I would do this by simply unmounting the partition so that the system isn't accessing it anymore. But because macOS is automatically creating a synthesized device from this APFS partition that contains all of its volumes, I can't restore it without the system going nuts as the partition's data changes out from under it.

How can I stop macOS from automatically creating the synthesized disk so that I can freely modify the raw data of this partition?

For example, if this is what `diskutil list` reports:

```
/dev/disk2 (external):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         499.9 GB   disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +499.9 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s2
   1:                APFS Volume MyDisk                  462.0 GB   disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 43.9 MB    disk3s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.5 MB   disk3s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk3s4
```

... then I want it to stop "synthesizing" `/dev/disk3` completely. Unmounting the volumes `disk3s1`-`disk3s4` is not good enough. And `diskutil` won't let me unmount `/dev/disk3`.

So far the only solution I've found is to do this on macOS 10.12 or earlier, since that system doesn't know about APFS. But I'd much rather do it on my main system running 10.14.

edit: I found one possible way of doing this: using GPT fdisk (gdisk) to change the APFS partition's type code to something that macOS won't handle (like `8301 Linux reserved`), unplug and replug the disk, write over the partition, then change the type code back to APFS. It's not a great solution. I'd much rather find something better.

Comment: How about installing a version of Linux. You could boot to Linux and use the `dd` command without having to worry about any APFS volumes mounting. Or, just boot to a USB flash drive Live version of a Linux and use the `dd` command.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yup, that's one possible method, similar to using macOS 10.12 and earlier. But it'd be nice if I could find a way to do it on my main Mojave system.

Comment: Personally, I like using VM's and Live OS USB to handle operations such as this. I have tried using `/etc/fstab` to block an occurrence of **macOS Mojave** on a **USB** drive to try and achieve the goal here, but just didn't have any luck with it. You might want to try for yourself. If you could safely script the use of `gdisk` to automate the process of changing the partition's type code then this may be you best bet if you don't want to use a Linux VM to handle the `dd` operations. (I like using **Linux** to use `pv` (_pipe view_) in conjunction with `dd`.) +1 for a good question.